# matplotlib | QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x831f000) is not the object's thread (0x95b40e0). Cannot move to target thread (0x831f000)

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, qobject, xcb

There were existing posts regarding this error, but not in conjunction with using `matplotlib`.

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x831f000) is not the object's thread (0x95b40e0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x831f000)

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, webgl.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the environment variable `QT_PLUGIN_PATH`, in terminal, may resolve the error:

```bash
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins
```

If not, install the dependencies:

```bash
sudo apt-get install libxcb1
```

```bash
pip install pyqt5
```